# Error: This is not a typed array when using gulp autoprefixer

Tags: gulp

I have the following gulp file:

```
'use strict'

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    rename = require("gulp-rename"),
    cssbeautify = require('gulp-cssbeautify'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('css-prefix', function() {
    return gulp.src('css/*.css')
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('Fcss'));
});
```

Now when i run the gulp command i get the folllowing error:

```
gulp css-prefix
```

[image]

Error: This is not a typed array.

Why am i getting this error ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you need to upgrade your node.js version to at least >= 4.5.  See [GitHub typed array issue](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-autoprefixer/issues/83)
 and [autoprefixer dependencies.](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-autoprefixer/blob/51886049f1b2bf1e3ac0631ef2a48137f4acfe10/package.json#L13)